# Bedeutung von "Seien Sie alle herzlich willkommen"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, subjunctive

Aus [Joachim Gaucks Rede](http://www.bundespraesident.de/SharedDocs/Reden/DE/Joachim-Gauck/Reden/2014/10/141009-Rede-zur-Demokratie.html):

> **Seien Sie alle herzlich willkommen** hier in Leipzig, dieser Stadt, in der vor 25 Jahren – am 9. Oktober 1989 – die Weichen gestellt wurden für das Ende der SED-Diktatur.

Warum wird der Imperativ statt des Indikativs **"Sie sind alle herzlich willkommen"** verwendet? Es ist schließlich kein Befehl oder Aufforderung, willkommen zu sein. Oder ist das eigentlich der Konjunktiv I wie "Es lebe die Königin"? Wenn so, warum ist  es nicht **"Sie seien alle herzlich willkommen"**?

Comment: Doch, es ist eine Aufforderung. Ein syntaktischer Befehl kann sehr wohl eine semantische Begrüßung sein. (Compare: "Be my guest!")

Comment: @KilianFoth Ach so. Ja, "Be my guest!" macht Sinn, aber "Be welcome!" würde auf Englisch sehr komisch klingen.

Comment: Wenn du aber einfach nur "Welcome!" sagst, würde ich das auch als Imperativ auffassen... Und ich vermute, daß klingt auf Englisch nicht ganz so komisch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt eine furchtbar lange und komplizierte Antwort dafür...die Kurzversion ist, dass hier der "Imperativ" steht, der syntaktisch ein durch Konjunktiv I vermittelter Jussiv, funktional aber ein echter Imperativ ist (Imperativ im Sinne der linguistischen Definition geht *nur* an die 2. Person!).

Ansonsten halte ich "Sei/Seien Sie willkommen!" für eine feste Wendung, ebenso "Sei gegrüßt", mit der Wunsch und Befehl gleichermaßen ausgedrückt werden: öffne ich die Türe und sage zu meinem Gast, "Seien Sie willkommen!", dann fordere ich ihn auf, meine Gastfreundschaft anzunehmen und hege gleichzeitig den Wunsch, dass sie sich als ausreichend erweist.

Answer (score -3):

Ich denke es sit eine Art "Political German", also eine geschwollene/hochtrabende Art zu sagen "Ich heiße Sie alle Herzlich Willkommen...".

Ich glaube nicht das dieser Satz mit einer höheren Bedeutung verbunden ist(Joachim Gauck *twinkle**twinkle*)

Comment: -1: Mit Politik hat das nichts zu tun, die Formulierung wird [häufig und in vielen Kontexten verwendet](https://www.google.de/search?q="seien+sie+*+herzlich+willkommen"). Und ich glaube nicht, daß der zweite Absatz mit irgendeiner hier relevanten höheren oder niederen Bedeutung verbunden ist.