# Usage of "sei" in imperative sentences

Tags: grammar-identification

> Peace be with us
>
> Gnade sei mit uns.

Could someone explain why Konjunktiv-1 conjugation of sein is used here? I think it'd be Konjunktiv-2 cause, it's expressing a wish.

Comment: Related [question in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/18283/1696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as English *God save the King.* That *save* is the English Konjunktiv I — present subjunctive. It's the only use for present subjunctive in English and seldom used.

In German you can find it more often. The name for it is *Jussiv*. It's not a wish but a command, and it's realized with *Konjunktiv I*.

> Ein jeder **kehre** vor seiner eigenen Tür, da hat er Dreck genug dafür.

You don't wish that everyone does that but you command it. The equivalent wish would be

> Ein jeder **kehrte** vor seiner eigenen Tür, es wäre so friedlich hier.

Comment: How can one command *Gnade*? What about *er ruhe in Frieden*, *so wahr mir Gott helfe*. *lang lebe die Königin*? These examples all seem like wishes to me.

Comment: That's why I always say Konjunktiv II isn't about wishes but non-facts. It's much more clear. If you say *So wahr mir Gott helfen würde.* you clearly feel that it's not a fact. If you say *So wahr mir Gott helfen werde.* (Konjunktiv I) this becomes more factual and *So wahr mir Gott helfen wird.* is already an assumption.

Comment: Hmm command, so how des that differ from imperative?

Comment: Imperative mood can only be used in second person. If you want to phrase a command to third person, you have to use the Jussiv.

Comment: The sentence is a wish rather than a command, so in my view it is more correct to use the term Optativ instead  of Jussiv. But this is of little practical importance as German can realize both Optativ and Jussiv with Konjunktiv I.